# PayPal API Rest & Merchant e-mail account

Tags: paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal

this is my question:

Is it possible to use the `PayPal API Rest` with my `API-KEY`, but with different merchant e-mail account for accept a payment?

I need to allow the users of my web application to connect their paypal account to receive payments on their paypal account. So can i set the target merchant e-mail of a payment using **API REST** or **CLASSIC API**?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately REST API does not have this functionality at this time. To do this you can use [Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/adaptive-payments/) to be the caller of the API and supply receiver email addresses, or [Permissions API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/permissions-service/integration-guide/PermissionsAbout/) to make Classic API calls for other users.